# Can't use history.push to async route, React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using this package https://github.com/SimpleContacts/react-router-async-routes

```
<Route
    async
    path={`${match.url}app`}
    render={async () => {
      try {
        Promise.all([await Axios.get('/api/loggedin')]).then((userData) => {
          this.props.setUser(userData[0].data);
        });
        return <MainApp />
      } catch (err) {
        return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: this.props.location } }} />
      }
    }}
  /> //history.push not working on this one.
<Route path={`${match.url}somepage`} component={SomeComp} /> // history.push works
```

When I use React Router's `history.push` to the custom async route `/app`, the url changes, redux route changes, but the App-component is not loaded. It's working on a "normal" route.

I can't identify where the problem is.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have nested `BrowserRouter `? I had a similar problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The await statment within the App Route render props callback method is at an incorrect place. It won't wait for `Promise.all` to resolve before returning the component. Also you simply can write your code without Promise.all as below

```
<Route
    async
    path={`${match.url}app`}
    render={async () => {
      try {
        const userData = await Axios.get('/api/loggedin')
        this.props.setUser(userData.data);
        return <MainApp />
      } catch (err) {
        return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: this.props.location } }} />
      }
    }}
  /> //history.push not working on this one.
<Route path={`${match.url}somepage`} component={SomeComp} />
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/w2788n1lr5)

> PS Make sure your API is giving you the correct response you are not
>   landing up in catch block

Comment: Can you make an example where you're at some other path and then use history.push('/app') ? Also, the reason for Promise.all is because in the actual code I have more calls.

Comment: If you wish to use Promise.all use the await outside of promise.all block. Sure I will work on the demo in some time

Comment: Please do. The await was just a mistype. It's not the problem.

Comment: @Joe Updated demo at the same link in the answer. Please check

Answer (score 0):

await the Promise.all and you should be fine but as someone else said earlier, it doesn't look like you need Promise.all at all(you only have one function in that array so you can ditch it altogether.

```
...
try {
  await Promise.all(...
```